# Large 2-digit numbers that factor into 2-digit numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

$799777779779979$ and $111111811818111$ are numbers of $2$ non-zero digits that can be factored into $2$-digit numbers. They are $97$-[smooth numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothNumber.html).

Are there any larger examples?

Comment: "numbers of 2 non-zero digits" means what?

Comment: Note that "friable" is a more descriptive and more modern term than the conventional "smooth" in this context.

Comment: According to my calculation, a larger example must have more than $20$ digits. The ratio of smooth numbers decreases drastically , so it is well possible that no larger example exists.